# Mixed UPDATE SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to run an UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE products
    SET fcategory = SELECT fcategory 
                    FROM categories 
                    WHERE categories.scategory = products.scategory
```

i.e. for the rows in "products" where column scategory = categories.scategory, products.fcategory must be updated to categories.fcategory

Example:

```
categories.scategory monkies, categories.category gorilla
products.scategory monkies
```

=> products.fcategory must be updated to gorilla since products.scategory = monkies = products.scategory

Anyone knows how to write such an UPDATE query?

Thanks.

Comment: What is wrong with your current statement?

Comment: Use a `JOIN` in the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: You could put the subquery in parentheses, so the query uses proper SQL syntax.

Comment: I'm still having a hard time understanding which monkey goes where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `JOIN`

```
UPDATE products AS p
JOIN categories AS c ON p.scategory = c.scategory
SET p.fcategory = c.scategory
```

Comment: ^ Yup. By the way your name is interesting, it could be translated to "breasts" in Icelandic :D

Comment: Excellent and quick answer. Thanks a lot.